# link to internal page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, hyperlink

I'm a newbie to wordpress, I added a new page via dashboard, and I want to make a link to this page from the home page so I would love to know what function does that,

I think it would be something like:
>LINK

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: <?php echo UNKNOWNFUNCTION('my_page_name') ?>

Answer (score 26):

You could use

```
<a href="<?php echo get_page_link( get_page_by_title( PAGE_NAME )->ID ); ?>">Link Title</a>
```

Where `PAGE_NAME` is the page title you have set in the dashboard.

[get_page_by_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) returns an object and we use `get_page_by_title( PAGE_NAME )->ID` to return the page ID of that page. Note that it is more consistent to rely on the page title (which you set yourself) against page ID (which is set by wordpress).

[get_page_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_link) retrieves the permalink of that page ID you passed as parameter.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply link to the page in the HTML body of the home page. For example:

`<a href="/index.php/your-page">your page</a>`

or

`<a href="index.php?page_id=###">your page</a>`

Where ###, put the post ID.

[More examples](http://codex.wordpress.org/Linking_Posts_Pages_and_Categories)

Edit:

If you are editing a template, and wish to obtain the permalink of the post using its ID, use `get_permalink($id)`

[More information about this function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)

Edit 2:

Based on your comments, you have to switch the permalink format. In WP Admin, find Permalink Settings, and set them to /%postname%/

[Read more about these settings here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Comment: yes but I would like to have something like: mysitename/mypage isn't it possible?

Comment: What is the URL you are getting for the page right now? You probably have to edit permalink format in WP Admin.

Comment: right now, in my main page (i m in local server) http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/ and I would like to have this url when I click on the link: http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/MYPAGENAME

Comment: I modified my permalink setting as you said and edited my link to  echo get_permalink('MYPAGENAME') when I click nothing happens and when I look at the source code, href is empty

Comment: get_permalink() excepts an ID, not a name. Where are you putting echo get_perma...?

Comment: i m putting it between my <a> </a tags .. where can I get the ID of my page?

Comment: Are you doing this in a template file, or are you still in Wordpress admin? If it's the latter, use what I suggested as the very first option in my answer.

Comment: I m doing it in my template file (my header)

Comment: You can find the page ID in WP Admin. Click edit on the page you want to obtain the permalink to, and you'll see the ID in the query string in your browser.

Comment: yes I tried it, but doesn't work either.. :( it links to the links in Dashboard .. I want a link to a page, I thought it would be simple.